# Is it possible to group by date, but sort by date + time in an xceed datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed-datagrid

I'm using the (community edition) of the Extended WPF Toolkit to display records that have a DateTime column.

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding ResponseInstructions, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        ReadOnly="True"
        AutoCreateColumns="False"
    >
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Created" Title="Request made">
            <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yy hh:mm\}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        </xcdg:Column>
        <!-- SNIP: Some other columns here... -->
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Notes" Title="Notes" Width="*" />
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

I'd like to be able to change the grouping behaviour of the DateTime column so that it groups by date (i.e. ignoring time), but to also retain the default sorting ability (i.e. date, then time).

If it weren't for the need to retain the default sorting functionality, I'd just change the column from DatetTime to Date. Is there a way to have my cake and eat it to?

Comment: you may perhaps sort the original collection by [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @pushpraj If you'd consider fleshing that out into an answer, there's now a bounty on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eventually I figured out that the desired can be done in pure xaml also.

here is the sample xaml

```
    <xcdg:Column FieldName="Created"
                    Title="Request made">
        <xcdg:Column.GroupDescription>
            <xcdg:DataGridGroupDescription PropertyName="Created.Day"/>
        </xcdg:Column.GroupDescription>
        <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yy hh:mm\}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
    </xcdg:Column>
```

result

[image: result]

in example above the sorting is based on the full date and time where as the grouping is on the Day property of the Created(DateTime) property

above example is based on some assumptions, I was not able to see your approach as `GroupByDate` resource from `GroupDescription="{StaticResource GroupByDate}"` was not mentioned in the question.

**EDIT**

as requested here is a way to change most aspects of the group including the top panel and the group header

```
<xcdg:DataGridControl ItemsSource="{Binding ResponseInstructions}"
                      ReadOnly="True"
                      AutoCreateColumns="False">
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:GroupByItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Title}"
                             Value="Created.Date">
                    <Setter Property="Content"
                            Value="Request made" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type xcdg:Group}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value,StringFormat=dd/MM/yy}" />
                <TextBlock Text=": " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Items.Count}" />
                <TextBlock Text=" request(s)" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources>
    <xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Created"
                     Title="Request made">
            <xcdg:Column.GroupDescription>
                <xcdg:DataGridGroupDescription PropertyName="Created.Date" />
            </xcdg:Column.GroupDescription>
            <xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yy hh:mm\}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </xcdg:Column.CellContentTemplate>
        </xcdg:Column>
        <!-- SNIP: Some other columns here... -->
        <xcdg:Column FieldName="Notes"
                     Title="Notes"
                     Width="*" />
    </xcdg:DataGridControl.Columns>
</xcdg:DataGridControl>
```

result

[image: result]

I have introduced one style for the top panel and a data template for the group header. I have used data triggers in the style to set the custom title as it seems like the data-grid has its own mechanism to retrieve the group title. Also I have modified the group property from Day to Date, as day was not the correct as it is only the day not the date.

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks simpler than I was expecting. Is it possible to change the name of the group, so that it doesn't display as "Created.Day"? (Also, the GroupDescription static resource was just leftover from my experimentations - I never got it to work.)

Comment: Thanks for your edit - we're definitely getting there. I've noticed a couple of problems though: Firstly, I don't seem to be able to sort by the DateTime column when I'm grouping on it. Secondly, I don't seem to be able to remove the grouping after I've added it (to the top bar). Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: not able to remove the group description seems like implementation issue with DataGridControl. once we change the text, it is not able to recognize the correct group description to remove. sorting seems to be fine, I clicked on header and it is able to sort normally. Lastly lets see how we can solve the grouping issue.